# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, numpy, encoding

I'm trying to write quite a complicated Python program, but it's mostly done. I am having trouble with just one tiny little detail.

The problematic code section is this:

```
newData = kmeans.sampleNewData(200, means, covariances, priors)

newData = newData.astype(str)
...loops and logic and stuff...
newData[i, j] = columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)]
```

Basically, `newData` is a numpy matrix size 200 by 4, filled with numbers of type float. I then convert them to strings use the `astype` method.

I then try to put this `columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)]` which is some string, into an entry of `newData`.

The problem is that `columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)]` is not necessarily English. It could for example be hebrew. In which case - I get the error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

It is worth noting that I have written `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` so we are encoding in utf-8, and when I print `columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)]` it indeed prints the correct value. So we can print it. But for some reason I can't put it into the `newData` matrix.

Comment: The `astype(str)` might be creating byte string array.  What is the `dtype`.  That's ASCII.  You may need to specify unicode dtype to hold these extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode is operation when you're trying to convert from some string type to bytes. It seems, that your `columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)]` contains Unicode string, so try

`newData[i, j] = columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)].encode('utf-8')`

instead.

Comment: Gives me the error "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: At first we need to figure out which types of data we can have. If we have float, not Unicode string, of course, there would be an error. So, try to verify the type of your cell value before do encoding or any. What types of data you may have there?

Comment: well when I print columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit)] it outputs "פרו" which is a string of hebrew text, meaning the country Peru. When I try to print its type I get the error "Unicode object has no attribute type"

Comment: How do you print the type? Try print(type(columnsList[j][(indexList[j]).index(closestFit))). I suppose that your data has various types. Unicode, str, float, smth else.